React Native app can't access HTTP URL on Android - what's wrong?
I'm trying to access this data source from a React Native app. The URL works great in a browser and in the RN app on iOS but not on Android where I just get a "fetch network error" with no HTTP response codes etc.
Here's a demo project
https://snack.expo.dev/PyhI0-ifGaoh0SygD_xIV?platform=android
What can be wrong since Android can't access this endpoint which seems to be a regular HTTPS GET operation that returns some JSON? Can anyone see what's going wrong?
I tried to inspect the network traffic with Charles Proxy, which didn't give me any clues but at least I can see that the requests are being sent from the device.
But I also noticed, that when running trough Charles Proxy with SSL enabled and a certificate installed, the above data source does not respond properly, not even on iOS or in a browser on MacOS. It seems like the response is being delivered, but the connection is not closed, and the client keeps waiting for it.
I'm not sure if this issue is related to the issue of RN apps on Android which cannot access the URL, but this is the only data source I've ever experienced that was not accessible through Charles Proxy and also not trough RN apps on Android?


It looks like a problem with handling the gzipped response.
Your app is making the request with okhttp and sending the Accept-Encoding: gzip header with it. Changing the fetch call to request uncompressed text seems to fix it, e.g.
fetch(url, {headers: {"Accept-Encoding": "identity"}})

